# Change color intervals in scilab colorbar

Tags: plot, colorbar, scilab

I want to change the color intervals in the colorbar in Scilab, in order not to have constant height of the different parts.

I was able to change the yticks location, and also the number of yticks,with the following code:

```
fig= gcf();
   cb = fig.children(1);
   cb.font_size = 3;
   cb.auto_ticks(2)="off";
   cb.y_ticks = tlist(["ticks","locations","labels"], yticks, string(yticks));
```

But I couldn't find a way to change the position where the color change. I searched thorougly in the colorbar function, and I think that possibily the solution is in the following part of the function, but I am not pretty sure, and also I do not know how to change the code.

```
   //draw the colorbar
    y = linspace(umin,umax,nb_colors)
    col=[colminmax(1):colminmax(2)]
    Sgrayplot([0 1],y,[col;col],colminmax=colminmax)
```

To give a clearer idea of the desired results, see the following image. I want the boundary of the different colors to fall exactly where my yticks are.

[Deisred result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnRX0.png)

Comment: Did my answer make any help for you?

Comment: Yes, it did! It is a "turnaround" solution, because it doesn't work in case I have irrational intervals (for example, color 1 for values from 0 to pi, and color 2 for colors from pi to 10). In this case the length of my cmap needs to be quite large in order to have my boundary fall at the exact location. I'd like to understand better how the colorbar function works, and how it plot the rectangle, but in the meantime, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, is by defining your own colormap. Below is my custom "reversed" jetcolormap code. By changing the `r`, `g`, and `b` arrays, you can modify the colors. If you don't need the flexibility for different number of colors, you can replace the interpolated `cmap` values vith hardcoded ones. If you need unequal distances between color changes, simply define the same color more than once, i.e.: white, white, pink, red, red, red, ...

```
//modification from jetcolormap
//reversing color order
function [cmap] = reverse_jetcolormap(varargin)
    // Check number of input argument
    if size(varargin)<>1 then
        error(msprintf(gettext("%s: Wrong number of input argument(s): %d expected.\n"), "reverse_jetcolormap", 1));
    end
    n=varargin(1);

    // Check type of input argument
    if typeof(n)<>"constant" then
        error(msprintf(gettext("%s: Wrong type for input argument #%d: An integer value expected.\n"), "reverse_jetcolormap", 1));
    end

    // Check if input argument is real
    if ~isreal(n) then
        error(msprintf(gettext("%s: Wrong type for input argument #%d: An integer value expected.\n"), "reverse_jetcolormap", 1));
    end

    // Check size of input argument
    if size(n,"*")<>1 then
        error(msprintf(gettext("%s: Wrong size for input argument #%d: An integer value expected.\n"), "reverse_jetcolormap", 1));
    end

    if n==0 then
        cmap = [];
        return
    end


//    r = [0.000 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.000 ; 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.500]
//    g = [0.000 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.000 ; 0.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.000 0.000]
//    b = [0.000 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.000 ; 0.500 1.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000]

    r = [0.000 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.000 ; 0.500 1.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000]
    g = [0.000 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.000 ; 0.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.000 0.000]
    b = [0.000 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875 1.000 ; 0.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 1.000 0.500]

    d = 0.5/max(n,1);
    x = linspace(d,1-d, n)
    cmap = [ interpln(r, x);...
    interpln(g, x);...
    interpln(b, x) ]';
    cmap = min(1, max(0 , cmap))  // normaly not necessary
endfunction
```